# How to remove a navigation controller in storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, swift

I am following a simple swift tutorial that shows how to add a navigation controller to a viewcontroller in storyboards in xcode. This is done using Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller

[image]

The problem is, once the navigation controller is embedded, it cannot be removed. The 'unembed' option is always greyed out. Removing the controller view from the storyboard results in an error. Even if the arrow indicating the first view is pointing to a simple empty view in exactly the same way as when you're starting a new project.

I would expect that there is still some code from the Navigation Controller lingering around somewhere, but how to pinpoint it?

Comment: remove link of navigation controller and make root view controller to your view controller.. than it works.

Comment: But how do I do that in the storyboard view? I can't find any code references anywhere. If I just move the 'arrow' in storyboard view I get this error: Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file

Comment: see my answer how I do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I follow this step.

1) select navigation controller and delete connection.

[image: select navigation controller]

2) make root view to your view controller

[image: make root view]

[image: root view]

Comment: I must be going crazy.... When I delete the navigation controller, the 'arrow' also disappears, so I can't set another view as the 'root'. When I completely delete every view, and then create a new view, I get the old error again: Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file

Comment: do same as shown in images and don't delete navigation controller at last step as i written in answer's last line. keep it disconnected as it is shown.

Comment: Thanks that was it. Great help!

Comment: ok then i will edit answer and remove last line for other user's reference.

Answer (score 3):

No...there is no source code, don't worry.

If your changes are hot then just Control-Z if not select navigation controller and press delete button.

Comment: When I do that, I get the following error: **Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file.**

Comment: assign the class name to viewController

Answer (score 0):

"unembed" function is for unembedding the "stack" in stackView and not for "navigation controller" nor "tab bar controller"